# jQuery UI themes and HTML tables

Tags: html, jquery-ui, html-table, themes, themeroller

Is there any way to theme an HTML table (CSS) with using the jQuery CSS themes?

All of my components look like they belong together except for my HTML table which looks different.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There are a bunch of resources out there:

Plugins with ThemeRoller support:

[jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

[DataTables.net](http://www.datatables.net/styling/themes)

UPDATE:  Here is something I put together that will style the table:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function ($) {
        $.fn.styleTable = function (options) {
            var defaults = {
                css: 'styleTable'
            };
            options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function () {

                input = $(this);
                input.addClass(options.css);

                input.find("tr").live('mouseover mouseout', function (event) {
                    if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
                        $(this).children("td").addClass("ui-state-hover");
                    } else {
                        $(this).children("td").removeClass("ui-state-hover");
                    }
                });

                input.find("th").addClass("ui-state-default");
                input.find("td").addClass("ui-widget-content");

                input.find("tr").each(function () {
                    $(this).children("td:not(:first)").addClass("first");
                    $(this).children("th:not(:first)").addClass("first");
                });
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Table1").styleTable();
    });

</script>

<table id="Table1" class="full">
    <tr>
        <th>one</th>
        <th>two</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS:

```
.styleTable { border-collapse: separate; }
.styleTable TD { font-weight: normal !important; padding: .4em; border-top-width: 0px !important; }
.styleTable TH { text-align: center; padding: .8em .4em; }
.styleTable TD.first, .styleTable TH.first { border-left-width: 0px !important; }
```

Answer (score 32):

dochoffiday's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2625525/50079) is a great starting point, but for me it did not cut it (the CSS part needed a buff) so I made a modified version with several improvements.

**[See it in action, then come back for the description](http://jsfiddle.net/defacer/UL2AG/)**.

### JavaScript

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.styleTable = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            css: 'ui-styled-table'
        };
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            $this = $(this);
            $this.addClass(options.css);

            $this.on('mouseover mouseout', 'tbody tr', function (event) {
                $(this).children().toggleClass("ui-state-hover",
                                               event.type == 'mouseover');
            });

            $this.find("th").addClass("ui-state-default");
            $this.find("td").addClass("ui-widget-content");
            $this.find("tr:last-child").addClass("last-child");
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Differences with the original version:

- the default CSS class has been changed to `ui-styled-table` (it sounds more consistent)
- the `.live` call was replaced with the recommended `.on` for jQuery 1.7 upwards
- the explicit conditional has been replaced by `.toggleClass` (a terser equivalent)
- code that sets the misleadingly-named CSS class `first` on table cells has been removed
- the code that dynamically adds `.last-child` to the last table row is necessary to fix a visual glitch on Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8; for browsers that support [`:last-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#last-child-pseudo) it is not necessary

### CSS

```
/* Internet Explorer 7: setting "separate" results in bad visuals; all other browsers work fine with either value. */
/* If set to "separate", then this rule is also needed to prevent double vertical borders on hover:
table.ui-styled-table tr * + th, table.ui-styled-table tr * + td  { border-left-width: 0px !important; } */
table.ui-styled-table { border-collapse: collapse; }

/* Undo the "bolding" that jQuery UI theme may cause on hovered elements
/* Internet Explorer 7: does not support "inherit", so use a MS proprietary expression along with an Internet Explorer <= 7 targeting hack
        to make the visuals consistent across all supported browsers */
table.ui-styled-table td.ui-state-hover {
    font-weight: inherit;
    *font-weight: expression(this.parentNode.currentStyle['fontWeight']);
}

/* Initally remove bottom border for all cells. */
table.ui-styled-table th, table.ui-styled-table td { border-bottom-width: 0px !important; }

/* Hovered-row cells should show bottom border (will be highlighted) */
table.ui-styled-table tbody tr:hover th,
table.ui-styled-table tbody tr:hover td
{ border-bottom-width: 1px !important; }

/* Remove top border if the above row is being hovered to prevent double horizontal borders. */
table.ui-styled-table tbody tr:hover + tr th,
table.ui-styled-table tbody tr:hover + tr td
{ border-top-width: 0px !important; }

/* Last-row cells should always show bottom border (not necessarily highlighted if not hovered). */
/* Internet Explorer 7, Internet Explorer 8: selector dependent on CSS classes because of no support for :last-child */
table.ui-styled-table tbody tr.last-child th,
table.ui-styled-table tbody tr.last-child td
{ border-bottom-width: 1px !important; }

/* Last-row cells should always show bottom border (not necessarily highlighted if not hovered). */
/* Internet Explorer 8 BUG: if these (unsupported) selectors are added to a rule, other selectors for that rule will stop working as well! */
/* Internet Explorer 9 and later, Firefox, Chrome: make sure the visuals are working even without the CSS classes crutch. */
table.ui-styled-table tbody tr:last-child th,
table.ui-styled-table tbody tr:last-child td
{ border-bottom-width: 1px !important; }
```

### Notes

I have tested this on Internet Explorer 7 and upwards, Firefox 11 and Google Chrome 18 and confirmed that it works perfectly. I have *not* tested reasonably earlier versions of Firefox and Chrome or any version of [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29); however, those browsers are well-known for good CSS support and since we are not using any bleeding-edge functionality here I assume it will work just fine there as well.

If you are not interested in Internet Explorer 7 support there is one CSS attribute (introduced with the star hack) that can go.

If you are not interested in Internet Explorer 8 support either, the CSS *and* JavaScript related to adding and targeting the `last-child` CSS class can go as well.

Answer (score 21):

Why noy just use the theme styles in the table? i.e.

```
<table>
  <thead class="ui-widget-header">
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </td>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="ui-widget-content">
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
      .
      .
      .
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And you don't need to use any code...

Comment: This is the simplest way to implement jquery-ui css and then build on it from there.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for tfoot too? This looks ok but maybe there is something more proper? `<tfoot class="ui-widget-header">`

Comment: I use <tfoot class="ui-widget-footer"> and add the line .ui-widget-header { border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;font-weight: bold; } to the css theme file ;-)

Comment: Can I add the class at the table level itself? Do you think it will work good?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a one liner to make HTML Tables look BootStrapped:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
```

The theme suits other controls and it supports alternate row highlighting.