# Border Color on tr is not applying on IE-7

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am finding an issue which is specific with IE-7. Working on FF, Chrome, IE 8/9. The issue is that IE 7 is not honoring border color on tr. Any workaround in CSS, Jquery, Javascript appreciated. http://jsfiddle.net/VW84N/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/VW84N/4/ without borders on `<tr>`

just use this CSS

```
table { border-right: 1px red solid; border-left: 1px red solid; }
td { border-bottom: 1px red solid; }
tr:first-child td { border-top: 1px red solid;  }
```

Comment: Thanks. your link does not work. But your code look like works for me.

Comment: I need to apply this on specific rows of table.

Comment: @user960567 then see if this other discussion can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923424/how-to-fix-inconsistent-rendering-of-adjacent-td-borders-when-they-are-collapsed/9924239#9924239 otherwise provide a fiddle with clear specification

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, but true: that's totally IE.

I've been using the workaround described here:

http://csarven.ca/tr-border-trick-for-ie

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-known issue. As a workaround, apply the border to the table cells instead of the row itself.

For example, an easy solution is to do:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0 } /* you have to do this */
table { border: 1px solid red } /* borders around the whole table */
table tr + tr td { border-top: 1px solid red } /* borders between rows */
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/defacer/txscq/)**.

Comment: But this will affect the sides of each td as well.

Comment: @user960567: I just finished updating with a working example. You don't have to add side borders if you don't want to.

Comment: I need to apply this on specific rows of table.

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
<tr style="border-color:yourcolor"><td>....</td></tr>
```